# An issue with the positon of a picture on xml

Tags: android, xml

I need a help!!
I need help to position my image as on the capture. I tried but to no avail. Below is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lyt_playbar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/albumArt"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="146dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_album_art"
        app:riv_border_color="@color/colorArtBorder"
        app:riv_mutate_background="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Screesnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9ktR.jpg)

Comment: what do you exactly mean by on the capture?

Comment: I meant that screenshot. I want to position the image in square like in the screenshot with the red marker.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it using relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffaa" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="146dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:background="#aaffaa">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Looks like this:

[image]